Difference between sostenible and sustentable
What is the difference between sostenible and sustentable?
I was reading something that said they could build something "sostenible y sustentable".
Google translates it as "sustainable and sustainable".
What's the difference between these two words?

https://www.bbva.com/es/sostenibilidad/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-sustentabilidad-y-sostenibilidad/ Salvo que se trate de vocabulario específico, para el común de la gente es lo mismo en cuanto se refiera al sentido ecológico. El resto es puro marketing agendista.

As pointed by tac, there is no difference at all. They are marked as synonyms in the DRAE.
sustentable


adj. Que se puede sustentar o defender con razones.
Sin.:  defendible, sostenible, razonable. Ant.:    insostenible.
adj. sostenible (‖ que se puede mantener sin agotar los recursos).


Notice that both words come from verbs sustentar and sostener respectively. Such verbs come directly from Latin verbs sustentāre and  sustinēre being the first one an intensified form of the latter according to the DRAE.
Apart of that, if you navigate through the entries of the Wictionary, you can find that those verbs also mean the same in Latin:
sustentare

sustentō (present infinitive sustentāre, perfect active sustentāvī,
supine sustentātum); first conjugation
to uphold, support, prop or sustain, maintainSynonyms: subsistō,
sufferō, sustineō, teneō

sustinere

sustineō (present infinitive sustinēre, perfect active sustinuī,
supine sustentum); second conjugation
to hold up or upright, uphold, support, sustainSynonyms: sustentō,
teneo, concipio, capesso, subsistō, suffero, capio, retineo

You can study the link provided by tac and try to understand by yourself the differences pointed there. I was not able and I'm a native speaker. For me such differences are totally artificial and made-up and do not correspond to the common usage.
I couldn't find the English version of that article in that web. In other articles translated to English there they always talk about sustainability alone. It probably means that they weren't able to establish any difference in English.
I've found this other article in the Wikipedia. Here is a relevant extract:

Es a partir de este informe cuando se acató el término inglés
sustainable development, y de ahí nació la confusión entre los
términos «desarrollo sostenible» y «desarrollo sustentable». La
diferencia es sustantiva ya que «desarrollo sostenible» implica un
proceso en el tiempo y espacio y va de la mano de la eficiencia, lo
cual le permite además ser eficaz. Mientras que el «desarrollo
sustentable» implica una finalidad (aquí/ahora) y va de la mano de la
eficacia, pero no necesariamente de la eficiencia. Por tanto, un
verdadero desarrollo sostenible implica por añadidura sustentabilidad,
pero la sustentabilidad no implica necesariamente sostenibilidad.

For me the last sentence does not make sense at all. One more time, this paragraph is not present in the English version. For me it's another proof that all of this is totally made-up and gibberish. You can translate sustainability to Spanish using sostenibilidad or sustentabilidad. In most places we use the first one. It looks that someone (a politician?) used the second one and tried to amend it saying that they are difference things.

For the first definition in the DLE which you quote I would translate that into English as supportable although I suppose sustainable would also work.

hmm...are you sure? I thought one had to do with financial sustainability and one was ecological sustainability?

@MichaelAltfield That differentiation is not present in the article linked by tac. As I said, it's not clear at all. That article even quotes the RAE and Fundeu, two of the main authorities in Spanish language, and they say that both words are synonyms. Google translation is correct.

According to the link provided by tac, and my memory, when in contexts of development, resources, ecology and so forth, it seems typical usage (i.e. in the 'collocations' sense) is:

desarrollo sustentable: considers only resources;
desarrollo sostenible: includes also the economy and society.

Also, you can say "insostenible" (meaning "no more" (a situation) or "unjustifiable" (e.g. a position or opinion), but not usually "insustentable".
Update: perhaps usage has been changing in favour of "sostenible", both in word choice and in meaning, to tend to include human activity.

But I think that there is nothing wrong about using "insustentable". It may be not so common compared with "insostenible" but it follows the rules about derived words: sustentar -> sustentable -> insustentable. And it means exactly the same. As it happens with sostenible and sustentable. You can check this other article and try to decipher the difference.

"Wrong" depends on what you are talking about. On one end of the spectrum, for "native" speakers there's no wrong, anything is just a means of communication. On the other end, for learners, "wrong" is measured compared to what natives usually do. Even word derivation is constrained by actual practice. And  "insustentable" is almost never used, compared to other words. Just that.

Yes, sure. In any case talking about insostenible vs insustentable is out-of-the-scope of the question. Have you found any source to back-up your main statements about desarrollo sustentable vs desarrollo sostenible. Something that sounds reasonable or valid.

@RubioRic Not really, just my experience as a native speaker. But let's see. There's Objetivos de desarrollo sotenible de la ONU (UN's Sustainable Development Goals); some speech about Ambiente y Desarrollo Sustentable; some Cepal publication about 'sustentabilidad'. I'll add an update.

ElapsedMilliseconds;
Google's ngram reports 'sostenible' always more frequent than 'sustentable, which I didn't expect.

Me refiero a textos donde se hable de la distinción. El NGram creo que está causado por traducciones del inglés, donde solo existe sustainability. Inicialmente se traduciría indistintamente usando sostenible y sustentable (más cercano a la grafía inglesa) y luego se ha acabado imponiendo "sostenible". Esas traducciones iniciales empleando los dos términos son las que han podido dar lugar a esta extraña y artificial dicotomia.
